# How to share functions in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, shared-libraries

Ok. this is simple but I had no success searching in internet.

I want to allow people to use the functions I make in Drive Scripts Editor, so that whoever that wants to use them in their own scripts can.

I want to be clear as I am not a programmer, so here is an example:

I have this script:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Then I want other people to just type:

```
function anothersFunction() {
  var x = Titleofproject.myFunction(1, 2);
}
```

In order to get a 3 for his x (obviously Titleofproject would be much larger).

The idea is to give them the possibility of using it, but not to see the project source code, at least for now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Shared Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) but note that this is against best practices and the page starts with this:

> Warning: A script that uses a library will not run as quickly as it would if all the code were contained within a single script project. Although libraries can make development and maintenance more convenient, you should avoid them in projects where speed is critical. Because of this issue, libraries should not be used in add-ons.

Comment: So, it is not a possibility to share a library without giving access to see the source code? Or am I mistaken?